# How to autoincrement particular field in Azure CosmosDB with MySQL API

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to implement an autoincrement functionality in Azure CosmosDB or using Node.js. I need to increment particular field every time item is inserted as it is done in PostgreSQL serial column type. This method should be reliable.

Let's say if we several requests are sent at once, there should not be situation where method generated the same number twice.

Thanks beforehands.

Answer (score 1):

There is no MYSQL API with Cosmos DB.

For other APIs, Cosmos DB does not support this.If you really look into it each document has an id property of type string which uniquely identifies the document, if you wish to achieve auto increment type functionality, you would need to handle this on your own.

There are plenty of JS libraries to generate UUID ,you can use them to do the job.

or use Trigger with Azure functions to update id.